# No errors, just doesn't print or do anything

Tags: python, list, iteration

I am pretty a beginner and I'm looking for help. I am supposed to write a simple programm which reads numbers from a file (they are ordered in two columns like this:

```
3 788506
255 879405
3 687899
255 697879 etc)
```

and always pairwise subtracts the number near 255 from the number near 3. The differences should be appended to a list. I also have to check whether the pair is rigt (e.g. that it's always 3 and 255 one after the other and not two 255s). So far I think I'm ready, but it doesn't do anything. I spent hours looking for my mistake, but I just cannot see what went wrong. I would appreciate any help.

```
filepath = "C:/liz/RT1-1.dat"
f = open (filepath, 'rU')
reac3 = []
reac255 = []
right_list = []
wrong_list = []
very_wrong_list =[]
li = [i.strip().split() for i in f.readlines()]
for element in li:
    if int(element[0]) == 3: reac3.append(element[-1])
    elif int(element[0]) == 255: reac255.append(element[-1])
k = 0
for i in range (0, len(li)+1, 2): #0,2,4,6,8 etc
    if li[i][0] == 3 and li[i+1][0] == 255:
            difference = int(reac255[k]) - int(reac3[k])
            print int(difference)
            k+=1
            if difference > 300 and difference < 1200: right_list.append(difference)
            else: wrong_list.append(difference)
    else: very_wrong_list.append(li[i])
print right_list
```

Answer (score 2):

`i.strip().split()` will return 2 strings .. therefore your comparison `li[i][0] == 3` & `li[i+1][0] == 5` should fail as `li[i][0]` & `li[i+1][0]` are still strings.

Also notice, that since `len(li)` should be even, then `xrange(0, len(li) + 1, 2)` will eventually make `i = len(li)` which should be out of the list boundaries.

Comment: Thanks. but doesn't split convert a string to a list? If I print the 'li' I get the list of the lists (where every line is a list).

Comment: compare li[i][0] with a string such as `li[i][0] == '3'`

Comment: it all goes fine until the moment I begin to iterate. I can print the reac3 and reac255 perfectly fine, but after that moment something fails.

Comment: Indeed it returns a list of Strings. And yes, if you print `li`, you'll get the list of lists.

Comment: You try to convert li[i][0] & li[i+1][0] to ints or compare with strings as '3' & '255'

Comment: yes, I tried to do it like this: if li[i][0] == '3' and li[i+1][0] == '255':
and it still returns the empty list at the end